# Make the type the values of an object in flow

Tags: flowtype

I have a file that exports a static object of key/value pairs:

const.js:

```
// @flow

export default const DEFAULTS = {
    myDefault: 'a',
    myDefaultB: 'b',
}
```

I'd like to say that the type of an object in another file is one of the values in `DEFAULTS`

main.js:

```
// @flow

import DEFAULTS from './const';

type MyReturnType = {|
    defaultValue = 'a' | 'b',
|}
```

Looking through the flow docs it seems like `$Values` is what I want - however,

```
type MyReturnType = {|
    defaultValue = $Values<DEFAULTS>,
|}
```

throws a flow error. If I prefix it with typeof, it works, though.

```
type MyReturnType = {|
    defaultValue = $Values<typeof DEFAULTS>,
|}
```

Is $Values correct? It seems to me like thats just saying it's a string, not necessarily limiting it to just `'a'` or `'b'`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to `$Values` to resolve literal types (e.g. `'a' | 'b'` instead of just `string`) it should be applied to frozen object:

```
const DEFAULTS = Object.freeze({
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
});

type DefaultValues = $Values<typeof DEFAULTS>;

const foo: DefaultValues = 'a'; // OK
const bar: DefaultValues = 'unexpected'; // string is incompatible with enum
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqAIgKIBiAggKoAyAKgMqgC8oA8gEYBWApitgHSQBOHDgC8OACgDeiUKACGALlAByWUoA000C0VKWSxAF8AlAG5k2AJ4AHDvg6RZAV2jYAarOiOOmBqAAk7p7eADyWNrCQ+MTk1DQAfGaoGDigkLCwinj2Ti6BXj6MKkomoCDMANJJWLgssvyZ2c5uHvm+So7oHAAeNtwcACbFpWA4-ACW6ADmoGM+E2gAtlay2GMs0LbwY9gAFqAc6I4LQA)